# Vue doesn't update the template when the value of ref changes Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, ref, computed-properties

Context: I want the progressbar to appear once the register action is running. But the computed function that is in the return isLoading does not reflect the changes in the DOM

Problem: I'm trying to simulate a loading when a back request is made. And my variable(isLoading) does not change in the template or DOM.

```html
<template>
  <div class="p-fluid p-card custom-login-box">
    <div class="p-card-header p-py-2">
      <div class="p-card-title p-text-center">{{t('login_signUp')}}</div>
      <div class="p-card-subtitle p-text-center">{{t('sign_up_subtitle')}}</div>
    </div>
    {{isLoading}}
    <div v-show="isLoading">
      <ProgressBar mode="indeterminate" style="height: .2em" />
    </div>
    <div class="p-card-body">
      <form>
        <div class="p-field p-mb-3">
          <div class="p-col-12">
            <span class="p-float-label p-input-icon-left">
              <i class="pi pi-id-card"></i>
              <InputText
                id="fullName"
                v-model="fullName"
                type="text"
                name="fullName"
                autocomplete="fullName"
                :class="{ 'p-invalid': errors.fullName }"
              />
              <label for="fullName">{{t('sign_up_full_name')}}</label>
            </span>
            <div class="p-error p-ml-5">{{ errors.fullName }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
....
</template>
```

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, computed, ref } from 'vue'
  import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
  import * as yup from 'yup'
  import { useField, useForm } from 'vee-validate'
  import { msg } from '@/plugins/toast'

  export default defineComponent({

    setup () {
      const { t } = useI18n()
      const state = ref(false)

      const validationSchema = computed(() => {
        return yup.object({
          fullName: yup.string().required(t('required')),
          email: yup.string().required(t('required')).email(t('emai_invalid')),
          password: yup.string().required(t('required')).matches(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})/, t('must_comply_suggestion')),
          confirmPassword: yup.string().oneOf([yup.ref('password'), null], t('matches_password')).required()
        })
      })

      const { errors, meta } = useForm({ validationSchema })

      const { value: fullName } = useField<string>('fullName')
      const { value: email } = useField<string>('email')
      const { value: password, meta: metaPassword } = useField<string>('password')
      const { value: confirmPassword } = useField<string>('confirmPassword')

      const register = async () => {
        console.log('valor inicial en loading', state.value)
        console.log('entro a la funcion')
        state.value = true
        console.log('el valor que le asigno a loading', state.value)
        await setTimeout(() => {
          const res:number = Math.round((Math.random() * (2 - 1) + 1))
          if (res === 1) {
            msg.showSuccess()
          } else {
            msg.showError(t('exist_email'))
          }
        }, 2000)
        state.value = false
        console.log('despues que termina la funcion', state.value)
      }

      return { t, fullName, email, password, confirmPassword, errors, meta, metaPassword, register, isLoading: computed(() => state.value) }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed with the Vue devtools that `isLoading` does not change state? v-show is notoriously sensitive and often the reason it doesn't update in the DOM is something other than the state not changing (in my experience). Cannot pinpoint here what could be wrong, though.

Comment: Why are you even using computed there and not just call the ref isLoading and using it directly?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) is Promise based (can be used only with promises) and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) does not return a Promise

So when the `register` method is executing it first sets `state.value` to `true`, then schedule a timeout and **immediately** sets the `state.value` to `false`. To make it work, move the `state.value = false` inside the `setTimeout` callback.

As you are using `setTimeout` only to simulate async call, when you replace the `setTimeout` with real Promise based async call such as `fetch`, the code will work as expected as is...